# Tensorflow: Incorrect training while using ImageDataGenerator. Giving 99% training accuracy despite model outputting only 1 class

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am creating a simple model that classifies human and horse. Doing this on Google Colab.

I am using the following two URLs for training and validation datasets.
https://storage.googleapis.com/laurencemoroney-blog.appspot.com/horse-or-human.zip
https://storage.googleapis.com/laurencemoroney-blog.appspot.com/validation-horse-or-human.zip

I saved the datasets in my tmp folder and then created image data generators for them

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/tmp/horse-or-human', target_size=(300, 300), color_mode='rgb',\
                                                    class_mode='binary', batch_size=128)
```

```
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('/tmp/validation-horse-or-human', target_size=(300, 300), \
                                                       color_mode='rgb', class_mode='binary', batch_size=128)
```

Here is the model I created and compiled

```
i = Input(shape=(300, 300, 3))

#Convolution 1
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu')(i)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)

#Convolution 2
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)

x = Flatten()(x)

x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(rate=dropout_rate)(x)
# x = Dense(100, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha))(x)
# x = Dropout(rate=dropout_rate)(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(i, x)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I then started training using the two generators

```
history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=8, epochs=5, validation_data=validation_generator)
```

[image]

From the training, it should be clear that it has overfitted. Also from the validation accuracy, I came to know that it was outputting probability of input being only 1 class (since 1 class is 51.31% of total). Further model.predict tests on **both** training and validation sets confirmed this.

I checked both the generators to see if one of them is supplying only 1 class data to the model. That is **not** the case.

```
labels = validation_generator[7][1]
print(len(labels[labels==0]))    #Output is 64 out of 128, Output is 64 also for labels==1
```

How is the model getting 100% training accuracy while training when it is returning output as only 1 class? Is there something with the train_generator that I am missing?

Comment: Can you log the output of the network to see if it keeps outputting values close to 0 or 1?

Comment: @tnfru It outputs value only close to 1

Comment: I see. I am still confused as to how the model is getting 99% accuracy while training when it is outputting just 1 class. Shouldn't the accuracy be around 50%?

Comment: I even experimented by using the same train_generator as validation_data to check. In such a case, again the training accuracy is still 99% but validation accuracy is around 50%.
This is weird since I am using the same entire dataset for both training and validation, and the accuracies are still different

Comment: I've missed that fact and so my old comment is wrong and I removed it.

Comment: Alright, I hope the question is clear now. If not, please do specify what you're looking for

Comment: It is not returning one class. It returns the *probability* of being class 1 or the first class.

Comment: @Frightera That is correct. My bad